# Getting started with RTMFP

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, red5, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

I need to implement a realtime connection between 2 or more players, that will play a Flash game.

I've read that RTMFP is a good choice to make this connection the best possible (were best=less lag between actions), but, Im quite new to this kind of things, what documentation/tutorial/guide you think would be the best to get started and finally make a good implementation of RTMFP?

Thanks in advance!

(Also, I read that there are differents servers or frameworks that provide the same, like Cirrus, Red5, etc, what pros and contras have this?, taking cost into acount)

Update: I was reading the adobe documentation, there is an example too, but I'd love to see some more flash game based example, even a very basic one, so I can extend that functionality and start making tests.

Update2: I got it working, now, I need to know how to make a webservice for the peer ID interconnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_cirrus_app.html
List of other articles:
http://www.flashrealtime.com/tag/cirrus/

Sample applications:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/
http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/07/rtmfp-connection-tester/